# how can I find python 3 codes only on github?

Tags: python, github, version

Is there a way to know which codes on github are in python 3? So far, I haven't any mentionned.

Tks

Answer (score 0):

Very simply:

- Yes, you can find Python3 code.
- No, you cannot do so effectively.

Code on GitHub is not identified by language and version -- obviously, since you would have found that in your investigations before coding.  Yes, you *can* generally determine the language of a code file, but only with detailed examination -- you would almost need to pass the file to a Python compiler and reject any with syntax errors.  This is not an effective process.

You can reduce the search somewhat by gleaning *.py files and then look for frequent, 3-specific features, such as all `print` commands using parentheses (coding style in Python 2, mandated in Python 3).  This merely reduces the problem; it does not give you a good request mechanism.